# the Facebook Hacker Cup 2013 Hackathon

Tags: java, алгоритм

Решаю https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/83/
мой код:

```
static void fb(String line){
    String s =line.toLowerCase();
    char[] Myarr=s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(Myarr);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(Myarr,'a'));
    int r=26;
    int ret=0;
    int k=0;
    boolean fl=false;
    int[] arrK=new int[Myarr.length];
    k=arrK.length;
    char ch='z'+1;
    for (int i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
        if (Myarr[i]==ch){
            arrK[k]++;
        }
        else {
            k--;
            ch=Myarr[i];
            arrK[k]++;
        }
        if (ch<'a') break;
    }
    k=arrK.length-1;
    for (int ii=k;ii>=0;ii--) {
        if (arrK[ii]==0) break;
        //System.out.print(ii);
        ret = ret + (r*arrK[ii]);
        r--;
    }
    /*
    for (char i='z';i>='a';i--){
        fl=false;
        while (true){
            k=Arrays.binarySearch(Myarr,i);
            if (k>=0){
                //System.out.print(i+":"+Arrays.binarySearch(Myarr,i)+" ");
                ret=r+ret;
                //System.out.print(ret+" ");
                fl=true;
                Myarr[k]=' ';
                Arrays.sort(Myarr);
                for (int jj=0;jj<Myarr.length;jj++){System.out.print(Myarr[jj]);}
                System.out.println("----"+r+" : "+ret);
            //System.out.print(i+":"+Arrays.binarySearch(Myarr,i)+" ");
            }
            else {
                if (fl){
                    r--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
*/
    System.out.println(line+":"+ret);/*
    for (int k=0;k<Myarr.length;k++){
        System.out.print(Myarr[k]+"|");
    }
    System.out.println("");*/
}
```

Для первой тестовой строки результат бьется, для остальных нет. Помогите!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас поймали на условии, алгоритм у вас неверный. Никто не говорил, что красота 'a' меньше красоты 'b'. Самая красивая буква - это та, количество которых во фразе больше всего. Только тогда красота фразы будет максимальной. Например, во второй фразе самые красивые 'c','e' и 'o', они встречаются по 4 раза. И красота у каждой из них соответственно 26, 25 и 24.

ЗЫ Код приведите в порядок...